# Using percentage values to fill flexbox items

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, flexbox

I use flexboxes in Google Chrome (only this browser has to be supported) to create a dynamic layout. I've got n child elements in one div element which should share the whole space with all the same ratio. This is working without problems due to the new introduced flex-boxes. But I also had to set the height of each inner div to 0. If I want to stretch an element inside this div to 100% height it uses the given value of 0 instead of any computed value. As I've chosen flex-boxes in order to prevent using javascript I would prefer remaining that way. Is there any other way to make the image's height filling the div?

And here is the code (only tested in Google Chrome):

html

```
<div class="flexbox">
    <div><img src="chrome-logo.png" /></div>
    <div><img src="chrome-logo.png" /></div>
    <div><img src="chrome-logo.png" /></div>
    <div><img src="chrome-logo.png" /></div>
</div>
```

css

```
            .flexbox {
                display:-webkit-box;
                -webkit-box-orient:vertical;
                height:300px;
                width:200px;
            }
            .flexbox > div {
                -webkit-box-flex:1;
                height:0;
                border:solid 1px #000000;
            }
            .flexbox > div > img {
                height:100%;
            }
```

[The code to watch in the browser](http://shiratamako.dyndns.org/stack/flexbox.htm)

Comment: Why did you have to set the height to 0?  If you're not going to explicitly set the height, what are you expecting the `100%` to be one hundred percent of?

Comment: I did that in order to divide the whole available space to parts of the same size. Otherwise only the remaining space (without the content) is assigned. It's the behavior like using the flex-function described in that mail: [http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2011Nov/0770.html](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2011Nov/0770.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well I got it working after hours of research.
The following changes are to do:

```
.flexbox {
            display:-webkit-box;
            -webkit-box-orient:vertical;
            height:300px;
            width:200px;
        }
        .flexbox > div {
            -webkit-box-flex:1;
            height:0;
            border:solid 1px #000000;
            position:relative; /* CHANGE */
        }
        .flexbox > div > img {
            height:100%;
            position:absolute; /* CHANGE */
        }
```

If you're intrested in you can make these changes via the ChromeDevTools to the css and you'll see the right result!

Comment: .. and don't forget to set `width: 100%;` for links :)